# Pattern along Path appears to be broken in InkScape 1.1

Tags: inkscape, patterns

In InkScape 1.1, I have a pattern of a laurel (created with Interpolate and then path -> combined) and a circle (no fill, just border and object to path) that I created as shown...

[image]

When I select both objects and go to Extensions -> Generate from Path -> Pattern along Path....

[image]

and I click "Live Preview", it jacks its up like this...

[image]

Sometimes it gets crazier than that!  Sometimes it wraps the circle around the laurel like so...

[image]

Wha is the most reliable way of getting my laurel to properly wrap around my circle in InkScape 1.1?

- Does document scale, or grid sizes matter?
- Does border size matter?
- Does Interpolate settings in InkScape 1.1 matter?
- Is there an alternative method of achieving the same exact thing if this process "is" broken?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Inkscape 1.1 is outdated. The current version is 1.2.2.  I don't think that is the issue here, but it's best to use the most recent version.  Pattern along a Path is certainly not broken in the most recent version, I can't remember if there were any issues with 1.1 TBH.

Your pattern is in a vertical direction. However, the default is for Inskscape to assume the pattern is horizonal. So, when you add the path effect make sure to choose the "Pattern is Vertical" setting. Also it looks like you've applied the circle as the pattern, instead of the pattern, though I can't be sure. That's only a guess.

I think it would be better to apply this to an segment of a circle rather than a a complete circle, then you can use the Mirror Symmetry path effect to reflect it after you've applied the Pattern on a Path effect. Also note that the path direction matters when applying a Pattern on a Path.

An example. This is actually using the Live Path Effects available in Inkscape 1.2.2

[image]

Comment: Thank you Billy, I followed your steps and I know have it working as you have demonstrated.  I have no clue what was going on prior.  I restarted InkScape, followed the steps, and now I'm good.  Many thanks.